# How to apply css3 keyframe animation to first row

Tags: html, css

How to apply `css3 keyframe animation` to first row of table. i used this code `tr:first-child td` but css is not getting applied to first row of table. where i made the mistake....suggest something.

```
<table id='gridId'>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### CSS

```
tr:first-child td {
  animation: pulse 2s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    background-color: Green;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do u need animation on th or td

Comment: the first `tr` contains `th`, not `td`

Comment: You don't have any td's inside your first tr :)

Comment: add class to first row i.e. for <tr class="some name"> & apply your css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tr:first-child th {
  animation: pulse 2s infinite alternate;
}
```